# How do I navigate once I submit a form and receive a status of 200

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am confused about how to navigate away from a form route in view to another route, once my data has been submitted successfully.

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747279/redirect-after-axios-response-with-vue).
Which seems like it should work, but it's a bit unclear on the Vue router side, can I instantiate a new Vue router in any component if I have a routes component already. Anyway, it seems to get the status but it doesn't push the route.

My Method:

```
methods: {
  handleSubmit(event) {
    const router = new VueRouter();
    axios.post(API_ENDPOINT,
    this.itemInit,
    { headers: {
      'Content-type' : 'application/json',
       }
    }).then(response => {
        this.results = response.data.results;
        if(response.status == 200) {
          router.push('/');
        }
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
  }
}
```

I am expecting to have it navigate to the root route when I get a status 200 from the server, which I am and everything works fine, just not getting this navigation.

Update: This worked for me.

```
methods: {
  handleSubmit(event) {
    const router = new VueRouter();
    axios.post(API_ENDPOINT,
    this.itemInit,
    { headers: {
      'Content-type' : 'application/json',
       }
    }).then(response => {
        this.results = response.data.results;
        if(response.status == 200) {
          this.$router.push('/');
        }
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main.js file (entry point to your app). I assume when you are creating your app you are attaching the router to the new Vue instance?

Comment: I could have sworn I added tried this several times before posting but adding this.$router.push('myRoute'); Worked. Maybe this post will help someone down the road.

Comment: Yep! I posted the basic setup below to exemplify mounting the router to the Vue instance then referencing just as you posted in your comment... right as you posted back. Glad you are up and running!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are building a single page app in your entry point (usually main.js)

You would do something similar to the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { router } from '@/plugins/vue-router' // This is where you declare your routes
```

and when you initiate your app you will have something like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Now in your component you would need to update your code to:

```
methods: {
  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post(API_ENDPOINT,
    this.itemInit,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.results = response.data.results;
      if(response.status == 200) {
        this.$router.push('/');
      }
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I eventually came to your solution as well.